# How to force Excel to recalculate circular dependencies after fixing an error?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a complex financial worksheet that uses intentional circular references.
Excel does a good job at calculating them, because I enabled iterative calculation.

Problem: when I accidentally create an error (e.g. #NUM or #DIV/0) by changing a formula of a cell used in a circular dependency, then fix it, Excel fails to recalculate the sheet.

Problem is easy to reproduce with a simple scenario, where tax=tax rate*(revenue+tax):

[image]

After fixing the error in C1, C2 stays with the original error and does not recalculate.

Using `Calculate now` does not help.
The only way I found to recover a functional worksheet is to edit (<kbd>F2</kbd>) C2 formula then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But this solution is not applicable to my complex worksheet: I get dozens of cells in error at once and cannot find the one I should "refresh" (<kbd>F2</kbd> then (<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

How can I solve this?
I'd just like to force Excel to *really* recalculate everything after fixing the error.

Comment: Haven't verified as an answer, so leaving this as a comment. CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + F9 should recheck formula dependencies and recalculate formulas.

Comment: @jrichall I just found this possible solution myself seconds ago and was hopeful as you were... but it does not work :/

Answer (score 2):

The only solution for that is to fill your model with =IFERROR([cell formula here], 0)
That was the only way I could figure out how to solve this iteration problem.
The rationale behind it is that Excel will try to iterate the worksheet calculations many times. The first will result in 0 for every cell that was resulting in errors. The second iteration will than start correctly.

Comment: The `IFERROR` function helps a lot in this case. For me, I use `1` as the default value instead of `0` to avoid other `#DIV/0` errors that depend on that cell.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution is to add a "circuit breaker" into your model.

This is a cell that holds a drop-down, boolean value (TRUE/FALSE), and on which the circular references depend via an IF statement.

A classic example, in an LBO model, you might have a circuit breaker for: "Interest depends upon average balance?".  If false, interest expense would depend upon beginning of the year debt balance, instead of average, which in turn depends upon cash flows available for early repayment, which in turn depends upon fixed charges, including interest expense.

If you blow the model up and the error propagates all the way through, you change this to false, most things get fixed, you fix the few things that are actually wrong, and then re-flip the switch.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing as there seems to be no solution to my initial question.

Answer (score 1):

> when I accidentally create an error (e.g. #NUM or #DIV/0) by changing a formula of a cell used in a circular dependency, then fix it, Excel fails to recalculate the sheet.

That's actually not true, Excel recalculates properly (at least in the example you've posted):

- when you enter a circular reference, like in your example:
  `=B1*(C1+C2)` in C2
- Excel interprets it just taking the values of the cell in the previous moment, and the previous value in C2 was an error, so your formula will be:
  `=B1*(C1+#ERR)`, which results in error, and whatever times you recalculate it, it'll still be an error, so the behaviour you've described is CORRECT
- if you hit F2, then you reset the value in C2, so it'll be considered as `0`, that's why it works
- you may argue you want to reset all formulas with an error, however that easily can end up in infinite loops when Excel try to resolve impossible calculations.

I've just a few times iterative calculations, however I very strongly advise against them, besides the your current issue there could be others too:

- lost of traceability: as calculation results depend not only on formulas and constants on the screen, but also on previous state, it can be very difficult (if not impossible) to reproduce situations
- if you change any value accidentaly which is a precedent of a circular reference formula, it'll be changed immediately, and it's not always easy to undo it (especially when you realize it several steps later).
- I think for a financial sheet, let it be anyhow theoretical / scientific / non-realistic you want to keep full control of the sheet.

Comment: Good points. But I have had no other problems so far with circular dependencies, and I'd like to keep them as they allow the formulas to stay relatively simple and their logic close to the tax rules I simulate (yes, law makers here *did* invent taxes which base includes the tax itself)

Comment: Maybe a macro could do the exact same thing as `F2`, `Enter` on all the cells?

Comment: Nevermind: on the real worksheet, a sequence of `F2`, `Enter` strokes on ALL cells does not work...